# Cache music streaming (Spotify) Location

Tags: streaming, cache, spotify

I am characterizing traffic from streaming services, specifically Spotify. I notice that a song is streamed once, and then, if the song is replayed, only few traffic is generated. Hence, that song is somewhere stored. I need that every time I play the song, this is again downloaded. I have tried removing contents on the `~/.cached/spotify` folder, but it does not work. Any suggestion to produce the desired effect? Or maybe a network cache what is occurring?